# User Profile Full Synchronization Service Breaks Display name and Email in FBA

Tags: user-profile-service, forms-authentication

I have User Profile Full Synchronization Service running daily. When it runs it tends to screw up a couple user accounts. Their emails are just removed completely, and their full name goes from "John Smith" to "i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|john.smith". The display name is mostly annoying, though it does cause some problems. However, the email being removed breaks workflows since that user can't receive emails they are suppose to get.

I set the Full Synchronization Service to run weekly to confirm that it was responsible for my problems. On Sunday instead of changing 4-5 accounts a day, it changed about 60 of them at once. Looks like it is making up for lost time.

We use FBA with claims based authentication. We use active directory for out service accounts and our SharePoint administrator. It takes an act of god for those accounts to change, so I am not to worried about them being synced.

Can I turn off the User Profile Full Synchronization service since I am using FBA? Is there a better solution? I am worried that a year from now, some administrator will go back in and turn it back on and trigger thousands of accounts being screwed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's overwriting the site collection user profile information with the user profile information from the user's 'My Site'.  If the user goes and fills out their My Site information, it will be synchronized across to the site collection.  If you don't plan on using the My Site feature, then you can just go and turn off the user profile synchronization, which will stop this from happening. (But your right - if somebody goes and turns it back on in the future, the full name and email address will get wiped out again).